# Turtle animation randomly speeding up/slowing down

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

How do I stop turtle animation from randomly speeding up/slowing down?

I have been trying to make a pong game with Python; however, the ball seems to speed up and slow down randomly from time to time.  How do I stop this from happening?

I have tried changing the speed variables of the ball, but that doesn't help. I've also researched a fix to this issue but I can't find anything useful.

```
import turtle

# Window settings
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title('Classic Pong v1.0')
wn.bgcolor('black')
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

# Ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape('square')
ball.color('white')
ball.penup()
ball.dx = 0.1   # Ball moves by 0.1 pixels every time
ball.dy = 0.1

# Main game loop
while True:
    wn.update()

    # Moving the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)    # Updates the position of the ball every time
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

    # Border collision checking
    if ball.ycor() > 290:
        ball.sety(290)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.ycor() < -280:      # Set to 280 to account for extra space
        ball.sety(-280)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.xcor() > 380:       # Set to 280 to account for extra space
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1


    if ball.xcor() < -390:
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1
```

I expect the animation of the ball to be smooth; however, the speed of the animation varies randomly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see off hand why your animation speeds up and slows down.  Regardless, below is how I would write this same code based on the following issues:

- A `while True:` loop has no place in an event-based environment like
  turtle -- if it's not a problem currently, it will become one.  I've
  replaced it with timer events.
- A pixel movement of 0.1 is awfully small and will always seem slow in
  turtle.
- Avoid asking turtle to do anything it doesn't need to in the critical loop. 
  Between calls to `setx()`, `sety()`, `xcor()`, `ycor()` and `goto()`
  you make a dozen method invocations on your turtle instance.  In my
  rewrite I just have two turtle calls in the critical loop, `position()` and
  `setposition()`.
- I dropped `tracer()` and `update()` as I instrumented my
  critical loop and there was only one turtle call that changed the
  screen on each update and that's the default setting for `tracer()`
  -- so nothing gained.

The revised code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

ball_dx = 1
ball_dy = -2.5

def move():
    global ball_dx, ball_dy

    x, y = ball.position()

    y += ball_dy

    # Border collision checking
    if not CURSOR_SIZE - HEIGHT/2 < y < HEIGHT/2 - CURSOR_SIZE:
        ball_dy *= -1

    x += ball_dx

    if not CURSOR_SIZE - WIDTH/2 < x < WIDTH/2 - CURSOR_SIZE:
        x = y = 0
        ball_dx *= -1

    ball.setposition(x, y)

    screen.ontimer(move, 50)

# Window settings
screen = Screen()
screen.title('Classic Pong v1.1')
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.bgcolor('black')

# Ball
ball = Turtle()
ball.shape('square')
ball.color('white')
ball.speed('fastest')
ball.penup()

move()
screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

**

```html
import turtle
import time  # change1


# Window settings
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title('Classic Pong v1.0')
wn.bgcolor('black')
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

# Ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape('square')
ball.color('white')
ball.penup()
ball.dx = 4              # Ball moves by 0.1 pixels every time
ball.dy = 4              # change3    you can move faster by change it to 8,8

# Main game loop
while True:
    wn.update()

    # Moving the ball
    # Updates the position of the ball every time
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)
    time.sleep(.03)  # change2
    # Border collision checking
    if ball.ycor() > 290:
        ball.sety(290)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.ycor() < -280:      # Set to 280 to account for extra space
        ball.sety(-280)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.xcor() > 380:       # Set to 280 to account for extra space
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1

    if ball.xcor() < -390:
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1
```

**

Comment: Please avoid code only answers. Try to include explanations as to what you have done, how you have done it and why.